# DAC to quad op-amp for Arduino FM synthesizer

Tags: operational-amplifier, dac, synthesizer

I'm working on a little Arduino digital synthesizer powered by an old Yamaha sound chip (YM2151).

I have a fairly good understanding of how to connect the YM2151 to the Arduino and the YM2151 to the DAC (YM3012), but I am struggling with understanding how the DAC connects to an op-amp.

This is a schematic of a similar device to what I am attempting to make. The amplifier circuit I understand is pictured above with the blue op-amp. I am used to the idea that the voltage gain is 1+R_F/R_2, but in the large schematic there doesn't seem to be an R_F at all. So what is this circuit doing exactly?

[image: non-inverting amplifier]

[image: schematic]

Answer (score 3):

Imagine sending \$R_f \to 0\$ and \$R_0 \to \infty\$. That makes \$R_0\$ effectively go away and \$R_f\$ be replaced with a wire in the schematic. Then you recover the subcomponent in the diagram you've posted. Plug those into the gain and you see \$G=1\$, so this is a unity gain amplifier.

Another way to see this is that an idealized opamp has the + and - terminals at equal voltages, and the output will do whatever it needs to do to make that happen. Since the output and the - terminal are connected, to make the voltage at the - terminal equal to the voltage on the + terminal, you just make the output equal to the voltage at +. Now you have a unity gain amplifier.

EDIT: The C4/R2/R3/C5 and following buffer with feedback from a Sallen-Key filter. [https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sallen–Key_topology](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sallen%E2%80%93Key_topology)

Answer (score 0):

The resistors and capacitors form a filter and the opamps are simply a buffer with a gain of 1. Rf in this instance is 0.